# Django ORM annotate performance

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django and Django REST Framework at work and we've been having some performance issues with couple endpoints lately. We started by making sure that the SQL part is optimized, no unnesecary N+1 queries, indexes where possible, etc.

Looking at the database part itself, it seems to be very fast (3 SQL queries total, under a second), even with larger datasets, but the API endpoint still took >5 seconds to return. I started profiling the Python code using couple different tools and the majority of time is always spent inside the `annotate` and `set_group_by` functions in Django.

[image: debug_toolbar_screenshot]

I tried Googling about `annotate` and performance, looking at Django docs, but there's no mention of it being a 'costly' operation, especially when used with the `F` function.

The `annotate` part of the code looks something like this:

```
qs = qs.annotate(
    foo_name=models.F("foo__core__name"),
    foo_birth_date=models.F("foo__core__birth_date"),
    bar_name=models.F("bar__core__name"),
    spam_id=models.F("baz__spam_id"),
    spam_name=models.F("baz__spam__core__name"),
    spam_start_date=models.F("baz__spam__core__start_date"),
    eggs_id=models.F("baz__spam__core___eggs_id"),
    eggs_name=models.F("baz__spam__eggs__core___name"),
)

qs = (
    qs.order_by("foo_id", "eggs_id", "-spam_start_date", "bar_name")
    .values(
        "foo_name",
        "foo_birth_date",
        "bar_name",
        "spam_id",
        "spam_name",
        "eggs_id",
        "eggs_name",
    )
    .distinct()
)
```

The query is quite big, spans multiple relatonships, so I was sure that the problem is database related, but it doesn't seem to be. All the `select_related` and `prefetch_related` are there, indexes too.

I tried rewriting the code without `annotate` at all, but it didn't seem to help. I started wondering wether the time spent in `annotate` is really a red herring and it's only how the profiler sees it, but all profilers I tried showed the same thing.

While I feel like I know Django quite well and had success optimizing API endoints before, I'm not sure what 'thread' to pull in this case. I tried looking at Django internals, especially around `annotate` and `set_group_by` but couldn't pin point the time spent there. My last ditch effort will be trying to rewrite those couple endpoints with raw SQL, but I'd very much like to avoid that.

All help will be much appriciated : )

Comment: Likely this is because *per* annotation, it will run the `set_group_by`, and a `set_group_by` runs linear with the number of annotations already done, hence it is quadratic. I propose you make a ticket for this: https://code.djangoproject.com/query since it indeed does not scale very well for a larger number of `.annotate`/`.alias` calls.

Comment: Can you do me a favour? Please put an ER diagram belongs to your running queries. I think no more than 6 tables, right? I had the same issue, but you wouldn't like the way I resolved it.

Comment: can you share your serializers & views please?

Comment: @KushanGunasekera as you can see / guess by the the number of `__` reverse relationships, there is a lot of tables and foreign keys involved. Still, there are a lot of indexes and the actual DB query takes _very_ little time, so I do think the bottleneck is the Django ORM.

Comment: @auvipy because of the complexity of the query, there is no DRF serializer on this view. The snippet above and surrounding ORM code is the 'complex' part. That said, I'll try to add more context later tonight.

Comment: Use cProfile and see what line actually takes all the time. Your screenshot doesn't provide such info.

Comment: Recently I read this  [article](https://hakibenita.com/django-rest-framework-slow). The article address the problem with slow performance on serialization with DRF, maybe that's another option you could look at it.